# How to set CutePDF to print immediately

Tags: printing, webpage, cutepdf

I use CutePDF to emulate a printing of a webpage, but in the default it only saves a .pdf copy of the webpage to be printed and then its gone with the wind leaving a copy of the file to where you have saved it. How do I set CutePDF so that it will preview the file first?

Comment: I would change the wording to preview instead of print, since CutePDF is a PDF PRINTER, so creating a pdf is considered printing ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you print to a printer, you don't expect it to give you a preview first, do you? (How would that work, anyway - a draft printout?) CutePDF works the same way. If you want to preview the output before "printing" it, use the Print Preview function of the application. (If your browser doesn't have Print Preview <cough>Chrome</cough>, get a better browser.)

Comment: yes I use chrome but it doesnt work in firefox either

Comment: What doesn't work in Firefox? Print Preview? Sure it does - File menu, Print Preview. It's the item *above* Print. The point is, this is an application (in this case, browser) function, NOT something you should expect your printer to do, whether that printer is an HP Deskjet or CutePDF.